# Issue Releted to Parameter in RDLC Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ASP.Net Application in Visual Studio 2008.
I have added Report Parameter in RDLC Report, I want to draw Parameter in my rdlc Report in Design View, but i dont find `"Report Data Panel"` in my ASP.Net Application... i Tried `ALT+CTR+D` but it doesn't work.
How can i draw Parameter in my RDLC Report design?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer : but i can't see "Report Data" option in View Menu in `ASP.NET`
i can see this option in `Windows Application`  in Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

- Open the rdlc file in Visual Studio
- Click on View menu
- Click on Report Data

Answer (score 0):

To make the window display, it's easy to find, but in a slighty different place than the usual (not under the "Other Windows" section). It is located on the View menu itself, in my case, the last option on the menu, named "Report Data".

**View --> Report Data**

Reference: [View Report Data window in Visual Studio 2008 / SRS 2008](http://chrisghardwick.blogspot.com/2009/03/view-report-data-window-in-visual.html)